# Could Donald Trump reverse Chelsea Manning's commutation?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump

As Barack Obama delivered the [commutation to Chelsea Manning's](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/jan/17/chelsea-manning-sentence-commuted-barack-obama) 35 year sentence down to 7, would President-elect Donald Trump have the ability to reverse that when he becomes President?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**No.**

The power of a Presidential Pardon comes from the Constitution ([Article II, Section 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Section_2:_Presidential_powers)) and there is no provision for undoing it.

Comment: Does it matter that it's a commutation with a future date instead of an immediate pardon?

Comment: @Bobson: Heck no.

Comment: @Bobson No, a commutation is a reduction in sentence. Obama has effectively reduced Manning's sentence by many years. There is no Constitutional power afforded the president to *lengthen* a sentence, that would invite retribution on political enemies

Comment: There's a chance he can try to get Manning re-charged with something else, but I'm unsure how Double Jeopardy would play with that ([I asked on Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/16479/are-charges-that-have-been-pleaded-out-of-subject-to-double-jeopardy))

Comment: @JRaymond - Logically, if you can pardon an offense in its entirety, then you can partially commute the sentence for it.  But the constitutional language is "Reprieves and Pardons".  If commuting part of the sentence doesn't count as either a reprieve (which it may?) or a pardon (which I doubt, since that's closer to "it never happened"), then it's **not** a specifically enumerated power.

Comment: It's worth noting that commutation of a sentence and a pardon are slightly different when it comes to what rights Manning will have when she is released. There are certain civil rights which are regained when pardoned that are not when your sentence is commuted.

Comment: In theory you're right, in practice they can just jail chelsea manning again for any reason they like. The US government has long been in the habit of jailing american citizens indefinitely without trial if it suits them particularly.

Comment: @Bobson sentence commutation falls under the "reprieves" language and was first exercised by George Washington. Most of the people who wrote it were still kicking back then and would have been rather annoyed if that wasn't what they had intended (well they were anyway, but for different reasons)

Comment: @Magisch There are exactly two cases in the history of the U.S. of Americans citizens jailed indefinitely without trial and procedurally it isn't entirely clear if they are generally applicable valid precedents. Neither of those cases would even if they were precedents have any applicability to Manning.

Comment: @ohwilleke 2 that you KNOW about. We already know the US operates black site secret prisons and has a secret court system in place. Theorethically, they could have jailed tens of thousands and you wouldn't ever get to know.

Comment: @user4012 - See my answer to see how Double Jeopardy applies here.

Answer (score 7):

No, the commutation has been entered so that is set.  However he did not pardon the Private, he just commuted the sentence.

Manning was convicted under the [Uniform Code of Military Justice](http://www.ucmj.us/) in a general Courts Martial, not in the Federal Court of law.  Double jeopardy and the protection of the 5th amendment prohibition of such, does not apply here, with regards to the Federal Criminal courts.  So in theory the [DoJ](https://www.justice.gov/) could pursue federal criminal charges which may include espionage, treason, and many other serious charges.

While this is possible, I do not think it will happen, unless Manning decides to go out and make a spectacle  of herself.  This is likely a case where the government will be happy to allow Manning to drop out of the public limelight rather than keep the whole affair under a spotlight.

Comment: I think what you mean is that double jeopardy doesn't protect someone who has been convicted of military charges in a military court against prosecution in a civilian court on civilian charges arising from the same acts, not that it doesn't apply at all.  If it didn't apply at all, then the DoD could try Manning once again on the same charges for the same offences.

Comment: @Phoog yes I clarified that.

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 - I know there were a lot of questions about what actions by "contractors" were actually prosecuteable during the Iraq occupation, because of the lack of a civilian government and lack of civilian jurisdiction for the USA government.  That would be an interesting one to delve into further.